# Equivalent conditions for proper functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I was asked to show that a continuous application $f:\mathbb{R}^{N} \to  \mathbb{R}^{M}$ has the following equivalent conditions:

(i) $\lim\limits_{|x| \to \infty} |f(x)| = \infty$

(ii) preimage $f^{-1}(K)$ of every compact $K\in\mathbb{R}^{M} $ is compact.

It seems intuitif that a function that goes to infinity on both sides must have at some point a minimum, and so for any compact image, the preimage cannot be unbounded. Graphically it makes sense, but I couldn't put it in formal math and link both conditions. Can I have some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show that if $K \subset \mathbb{R}^M$ is bounded (say $\vert x \vert \leq M$ for all $x \in M$), then $f^{-1}(K)$ is bounded. Suppose otherwise. Then you can find a sequence of points $\{x_n\}$ in $f^{-1}(K)$ such that $\vert x_n \vert > 1$ (since $f^{-1}(K)$ is bounded), but since $f(x_n) \in K$, we have $f(x_n) \leq M$ for all $n$. This contradicts the assumption that $\lim_{\vert x \vert \to \infty}\vert f(x) \vert = \infty$.